# case sensitivity in ordering

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a text file (a.txt) that has a lot of English words, I would like to re-write the file on other text file (inOrder.txt)

The code that I have got right now is case sensitive so it will list the words starting with capital letters first A..B..C.. D..until..Z then start with the lower case a.. b.. c.. d.. .....z, I need it to order them regardless of the case of first letter.

This is my code:

```
f= open('a.txt', 'r+')
data = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
print sorted(data)

with open("inOrder.txt", "w") as f: f.write("\n".join(line for line in sorted(data) if line.strip()))
```

As well as this I would like to write the result on more than one column, they are about 8000 (words/ lines), I need each column to contain 1000 words for example, so I can end up with 8 columns.

I am working on python 2.7.8

Comment: You want multiple columns. How would the words be sorted? From left to right or from top to bottom?

Answer (score 6):

Python [sorted](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) method accepts `key` keyword argument.

```
sorted(iterable, key=str.lower)
```

It sorts iterable of elements, regardless to their case. Key must be a `callable` object.